# Should i always put class property inside a constructor in js?

Tags: javascript, web, es6-class

Is there any difference in JS between

```
class a{
    constructor(){
     this.something=“blah balh”
    }
}
```

And just

```
class a{
   something=“blah blah”
}
```

I know i need a constructor when i pass specific data for the new instance. But when the data is the same for all instances, is there any difference between these 2 ways? Should i use one of them over the other?

Comment: One works and the other throws a `SyntaxError`. The second version will work sometime in the future when [this proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) gets implemented.

Comment: There should be `"blah balh"` instead of `“blah balh”`, then there is no difference right now, but when you extend some class from a parent class, you need to call `super()` to get its properties

Answer (score 1):

If the property is the same for all classes and not specific to an instance, you wouldn't need to put it into the constructor necessarily (although you could).  The correct way to persist something that is the same across all instances would be to have a static variable in the class.

i.e.

```
class a{
    static something=“blah blah”
}
```

Comment: This is currently non-standard and is in stage 3 and so it won't work in many browsers (might be worth mentioning). Also, you're using `“` which will give a syntax error (I tried to edit it but you reversed it?)

Comment: This works in almost every browser at the moment except internet explorer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Comment: I believe that is for `static` method, not field declarations (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Field_declarations)

Comment: Ahh sorry I accidentally clicked revert, that is for the static method not for field